# Nosetests has problems with sshfs?

Tags: python, django, nose, sshfs

I have a django project on a host OSX machine, and i mounted this dir as a sshfs share in a virtualbox ubuntu guest. I also mapped uid and guid to my user's values (1000/1000) with `-o uid` and `-o guid` options.

For some reason, nose won't discover tests:

```
$ cd ~/mnt/myproj$ 
$ ./manage.py test hotels
$ ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
```

When I copy (from inside the guest) this very project to another folder, it works like a charm:

```
 $ cd ~/dev/
 $ cp -r ~/mnt/myproj .
 $ cd myproj
 $ ./manage.py test hotels
 $ ....S....<etc>
```

What am I missing here? I can run git (which is known not to work on network shares sometimes) with no problem.

Comment: at first case just a $nosetests will work fair